# Can I rewrite and sell the material of already published history of literature book in the form of Q & A?

Tags: publishing, copyright, self-publishing, book

Can I rewrite and sell the material of an already published book about the history of literature in the form of Q&A? The purpose is educational/competitive.

Will this be a breach of the Copy Right Act in India? The book was originally written 101 years ago.

Comment: Copyright lasts for 70 years so probably you can do with that book whatever you want, though some other restrictions might apply. I would always consult a lawyer.

Comment: Also, this question is a duplicate of a score of other questions, among them https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/how-to-publish-public-domain-books and https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10179/why-doesnt-everyone-publish-public-domain-books and https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/is-it-legal-to-use-an-old-painting-on-the-cover-of-a-book

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish public domain books?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/how-to-publish-public-domain-books)

Comment: Welcome to Writers!  This is a Q&A site and works differently than traditional discussion forums, our site [tour] may be helpful if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: Also, this is about copyright not in the US but in India.

Answer (score 2):

This site appears to contain a condensed (lol) version of copyright law for India:

http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=208015

> ## TERM OF COPYRIGHT
>
> #### Is copyright protected in perpetuity?
>
> No. It is protected for a limited period of time.
>
> #### What is the term of protection of copyright?
>
> The general rule is that copyright lasts for 60 years. In the case of
> original literary, dramatic, musical and artistic works the 60-year
> period is counted from the year following the death of the author. In
> the case of cinematograph films, sound recordings, photographs,
> posthumous publications, anonymous and pseudonymous publications,
> works of government and works of international organisations, the
> 60-year period is counted from the date of publication.

So, it looks like the answer is 60 years in India; but you should consult an expert (likely a lawyer, agent, or publisher) to ensure this is the right amount of time and that it is applicable to the work in question. In the U.S. this work you are looking at would be considered to be in the public domain and you could sell it exactly as is or tear it into the chunks you wanted.